# Skolem Hulls in $H_{\omega_2}$

Tags: logic, set-theory

Consider a model of the form $\mathfrak{A} = (H_{\omega_2}, \epsilon, \prec, f_0, f_1, ...)$, some expansion of $H_{\omega_2}$ in a countable language, with $\prec$ giving a well-order.  Does there exist an infinite set $z$ of uncountable ordinals, such that for every $y \subseteq z$, $Sk^{\mathfrak{A}}(y) \cap z = y$?

**Edit:** In response to a question, I note the following are equivalent for a given infinite $z \subseteq \omega_2$.

1. For all $y \subseteq z$, $Sk^{\mathfrak{A}}(y) \cap z = y$.
2. For all infinite $y \subseteq z$, $Sk^{\mathfrak{A}}(y) \cap z = y$.
3. For all finite $y \subseteq z$, $Sk^{\mathfrak{A}}(y) \cap z = y$.

Proof: Clearly (1) implies (2) and (3).  I will show (2) and (3) are equivalent, which suffices because their conjunction implies (1).

Suppose there is some finite $y_0 \subseteq z$ such that $Sk^{\mathfrak{A}}(y_0) \cap z \not= y_0$.  Then there is some $x \in z$ and some Skolem functions $g_0,...,g_n$ such that $g_0 \circ \cdots \circ g_n(y_0) = x \notin y_0$.  Let $y_1 = z \setminus \{ x \}$; this is infinite and its Skolem closure includes $x$.

Suppose there is some infinite $y_1 \subseteq z$ such that $Sk^{\mathfrak{A}}(y_1) \cap z \not= y_1$.  Then there is some finite subset $y_0$ and some $x \in z$ and some Skolem functions $g_0,...,g_n$ such that $g_0 \circ \cdots \circ g_n(y_0) = x \notin y_1$.  So $Sk^{\mathfrak{A}}(y_0) \cap z \not= y_0$.

Comment: Are there any cardinal arithmetic assumptions going on? (In particular $2^{\aleph_0}$ and $2^{\aleph_1}$)

Comment: I haven't assumed any, but I would count as an answer any solution that is conditioned on some cardinal arithmetic assumption, or even something like PFA or Chang's Conjecture.

Comment: Can you do it for every finite n? For example, can you find a set of 100 ordinals such that none is in the hull of the other 99?

Comment: I don't even know how to do it for 3.

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the size of $y$? In particular, can it be infinite too?

Comment: @tci- Great question.  I will address it in an edit.

Comment: @mbsq Thanks for that observation! I suspected that something of the sort should hold, but nothing quite as nice.

Comment: I answered this question on MO at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/158293/ .